# Compare 2 immutable lists for equality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, immutable.js, reselect

Im looking to do something that I would have thought was done so many times with Immutable.js Lists already but i can't seem to find this case.  I have 2 lists.  One with Items.  And one that contains keys of the items selected as data.  users who have selected things from items basically.  I am storing the key from items as data in the profile of the user that selected the item (in a firebase db, not that it matters).  So I want to simply filter the items in my app using a selector.  In the selector Im looking to compare the key from items with the key I stored in the users profile. 
 If it's a match, then give me the matching data from items as state to use.  I believe this should be a filter on Items of some kind??  To do the compare i also need to get the stored key data in the users profile to compare which is also a immutable list.

Im trying

```
   const selectedItems = items.filter(
    item => {
      userItems.forEach(userItem => {
       if (userItem.itemKey === item.key) {
          return item  <-------pretty sure this is where  Im doing it wrong
       }
     })
   });
```

If i hard code a record from my users profile and filter, I get what I expect which is new filtered list with one item matching the id below.

```
  const selectedItems = items.filter(
    item => {
     return item.get('key') === '-LDR5cNZPjthN6nK9tzJ'
    });
```

Comment: use a map instead of foreach - map returns an array whereas foreach does not . `userItems.map(`

Comment: Yes, I see your point there.  I just swtiched. No difference though.

Comment: can you pass in a sample of `selectedItems` + `selectedTeam` and the expected return result

Comment: Tholle's solution worked well.  Filter just needed boolean.  Using array.some  with the filter made the most sense.  Was most elegant.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will create a new array with every element in the original array that returned a truthy value. With this in mind you could use a combination of `filter` and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to filter out all the objects you have a key for in `userItems`:

```
const selectedItems = items.filter(item =>
  userItems.some(userItem => userItem.itemKey === item.itemKey)
);
```

Comment: That looks right. Im still not returning any values though.  Let me test it some more.  I will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: so it mostly works if I add a return to the second line here of your suggested code above.  but I only get one value back instead of an expected 2 items that I know my user selected.  thoughts??

Comment: const selectedItems = items.filter(item =>
return  userItems.some(userItem => userItem.itemKey === item.itemKey)
);

Comment: @Puerto Try and copy/paste the code in my answer and see if you get a different result. There are some subtle differences with `{` and `(` and [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_Syntax). If that doesn't work it will be hard to say without seeing how your data looks, I'm afraid.

Comment: oh yeah!  haha.  hold on.  The above code is not exactly from my code editor.

Comment: Ok, yeah. No more return necessary.  Thanks!  I have some other cleanup but this is good.  thank you!!

Comment: @Puerto Awesome! No problem.

Comment: Just starting to see/get the power of selectors.  so whole new world for me.  :)